# GMail Api Socket Timeout from AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, gmail-api

We've been developing a system that integrates with the GMail API via the Java SDK. The implementation works well when hosted outside of AWS. But when the same code is placed into our AWS EC2 instances, we receive socket timeouts (even with 6 minute timeouts) about 50% of the time. We have done extensive firewall, routing, and proxy checks - but have found nothing that should cause an issue. We integrate with many other similar APIs (including Google Drive) and none of them exhibit this problem. There are no errors shown in the GMail API developer console.

Is there some sort of rate limiter for AWS based GMail API clients?

Can someone from the GMail API team help me troubleshoot this connectivity issue?

Comment: Not from the Gmail API team, so just shooting in the dark here. :) Have you noticed any trends in the requests that fail? 50% of all requests, or are there certain requests that fail all the time? I.e. does listing of labels fail, whilst listing of messages does not, or is it scrambled?

Comment: AWS doesn't like working with GMail. We had the exact same problem with them and we had to install some sort of third party SMTP service directly on our server which forwarded our mails. Long story short, you'll have to speak to the AWS guys. Their servers need to have something special done to them to get GMail to work. Unfortunately I wasn't involved in the whole process so I can't tell you exactly what was done.

Comment: I presume you're talking about the Gmail HTTP REST API?  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/  If so, I can't see any reason why it would behave badly differently on EC2 or any other service.  We have API frontends all over the world so they should be within 20ms from most anywhere there's a large cloud presence.  If EC2 lets you chose where to run it (US vs Europe) maybe try switching that, otherwise I think it's fair to say it's an EC2 problem.

Comment: Eric, yes, I'm referring to the HTTP REST API. My code is running in some EC2 instances in us-east-1 a,b,&c in a private VPC. I'll try to dig through the network topology and endpoints that the code is using to reach the Gmail API. But can you confirm to me that there is no mechanism infront of the Gmail REST API that should cause a socket time out? In other words, even if I was doing something wrong like hitting a request/sec threshold, would that result in no TCP response, or would I get some other different error?